# How to vectorize conditional triple nested for loop - MATLAB

Tags: matlab, multidimensional-array, vectorization

I have two 3D arrays:

*shape* is a **240 x 121 x 10958** array 
*area* is a **240 x 1 x 10958** array

The values of the arrays are of the type double. Both have NaN as fill values where there is no relevant data.

For each [240 x 121] page of the *shape* array, there are several elements filled by the same number. For example, there will be a block of 1s, a block of 2s, etc. For each corresponding page of the *area* array there is a single column of numeric values 240 rows long. What I need to do is progressively go through each page of the *shape* array (moving along the 3rd, 10958-long axis) and replace each numbered element in that page with the number that fills the row of the matching number in the *area* array.

For example, if I'm looking at `shape(:,:,500)`, I want to replace all the 8s on that page with `area(8,1,500)`. I need to do this for numbers 1 through 20, and I need to do it for all 10958 pages of the array.

If I extract a single page and only replace one number I can get it to work:

```
shapetest = shape(:,:,500);
shapetest(shapetest==8)=area(8,1,500);
```

This does exactly what I need for one page and for one number. Going through numbers 1-20 with a for loop doesn't seem like an issue, but I can't find a vectorized way to do this for all the pages of the original 3D array. In fact, I couldn't even get it work for a single page without extracting that page as its own matrix like I did above. I tried things like this to no avail:

```
shape(shape(:,:,500)==8)=area(8,1,500);
```

If I can't do it for one page, I'm even more lost as to how to do it for all at once. But I'm inexperienced in MATLAB, and I think I am just ignorant of the proper syntax.

Instead, I ended up using a cell array and the following very inefficient nested for loops:

```
MyCell=num2cell(shape,[2 1]);
shapetest3=reshape(MyCell,1,10958);

for w=1:numel(shapetest3)
     test_result{1,w}=zeros(121,240)*NaN;
end  
 
for k=1:10958
    for i=1:29040 % 121 x 240
        for n=1:20
            if shapetest3{1,k}(i)==n
                test_result{1,k}(i)=area(n,1,k);
            end
        end
    end
end
```

This gets the job done, and I can easily turn it back to an array, but it is very slow, and I am confident there is a *much* better vectorized way. I'd appreciate any help or tips. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm getting an "Array indices must be positive integers or logical values" error. The data type of the arrays is double. Could that be the issue?  

Also, both the shape and area arrays have  fill values of NaN. I realized I should have mentioned that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To vectorize the mapping operation, we can use `shape` as an index into `area`. But because the mapping is different for each plane, we need to loop over the planes to accomplish this. In short, it'll look like this:

```matlab
test_result = zeros(size(shape)); % pre-allocate output
for k=1:size(area,3)              % loop over planes
   lut = area(:,1,k);
   test_result(:,:,k) = lut(shape(:,:,k));
end
```

The above only works if `shape` only contains integer values in the range [1,N], where `N = size(area,1)`. That is, for other values in `shape` we'll be doing wrong indexing. We will need to fix `shape` to avoid this. The question here is, what do we want to do with those out-of-range values?

As an example, preparing `shape` to deal with NaN values:

```matlab
code = size(area,1) + 1; % this is an unused code word
shape(isnan(shape)) = code;
area(code,1,:) = NaN;
```

This replaces all NaN values in `shape` with the value `code`, which is one larger than any code value we were mapping. Then, we extend `area` to have one more value, a value for the input `code`. The value we fill in here is the value that the output `test_result` will have where `shape` is NaN. In this case, we write NaN, such that NaN in the input maps to NaN in the output.

Something similar can be done with values below 0 and above 240 (`shape(shape<1 | shape>240) = code`), or with non-integer values (`shape(mod(shape,1)~=0) = code`).

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you! Replaced an execution time of about 10 min with one of approximately 1.67 seconds.